# Iterate through each object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, foreach

I am having this object:

```
product: {
    id: "id1",
    title: "ProductName 1",
    additionalDetails: {
        o1: {
            id: "pp1", 
            label: "Text",
            content: [{ id: "ppp1", label: "Tetetet" }]
        },
        o2: {
            id: "pp2", 
            label: "Text2", 
            content: [{ id: "ppp2", label: "Tetetet2" }]
        } 
    }
}
```

I try to iterate to each object.additionalDetails.object but I cannot. My code:

```js
Object.keys(product.additionalDetails).forEach((key: string) => {
  const additionalDetail = product[key];
  const idLabel: string = additionalDetail.id;
  const label: string = additionalDetail.label;
  const contentId: string = additionalDetail.content[0].id;
  const content = additionalDetail.content[1].label;
});
```

But it does not work. What am I missing?

Comment: `additionalDetail.content` is an array and you're trying to access its `id` property (`additionalDetail.content.id`), since it always seems to have only one element, you can use `additionalDetail.content[0].id`

Comment: That doesn't look like correct syntax.  Are you missing `{}` to wrap `o1` and `o2` in `product`?

Comment: Hi Catherine:

Your first code snippet is not syntactically valid TypeScript. Are you sure you have copied it correctly?

Comment: @BenWainwright It is just smr quick I did to present my product object.

Comment: Secondly: "It doesn't work" isn't usually very helpful for those trying to help you. Please include an exact description of what exactly what happens including full error messages etc.

Comment: ok. But as @zero298 says - did you mean to wrap o1 and o2 in braces?

Comment: `additionalDetails` is an object, not an array. It's missing `{ }` for that matter. But anyway an object is not iterable with .forEach

Comment: @JeremyThille exactly. how can i iterate through it?

Comment: @BenWainwright he is right but I again have a problem. I updated my post. See please.

Comment: @zero298 you are right but I have again a problem. I updated my post. See please.

Comment: Well you already know how to do it :) You're already using `Object.keys()` in your code. Also be aware of the existence of `Object.values()`

Comment: @JeremyThille yes but it does not work :(

Comment: @KathrineHanson As I've already said once; "it does not work" will not help people help you. Please give specific details of what behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: @JeremyThille it does not even get to the loop. when I do console.log(product.additionalDetails); , I am getting o1 and o2.

Comment: That is because you need to use `product.additionalDetails[key]` not just `product[key]`.

Comment: @Titus thanks. if my content[] array is empty in some objects, would it be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that will cause an error, you can prevent it using `const contentId: string = additionalDetail.content.length ? additionalDetail.content[0].id : undefined;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two errors :

Replace `product[key]` with `product.additionalDetails[key]`

and

`additionalDetail.content[1]` doesn't exist (`content` is an array with only one element inside)

```js
product= {
  id: "id1",
  title: "ProductName 1",
  additionalDetails: {
    o1: {
      id: "pp1",
      label: "Text",
      content: [{
        id: "ppp1",
        label: "Tetetet"
      }]
    },
    o2: {
      id: "pp2",
      label: "Text2",
      content: [{
        id: "ppp2",
        label: "Tetetet2"
      }]
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(product.additionalDetails).forEach( key => {
  const additionalDetail = product.additionalDetails[key]; // <-- Here
  const idLabel = additionalDetail.id;
  const label= additionalDetail.label;
  const contentId = additionalDetail.content[0].id;
  // const content = additionalDetail.content[1].label;  // <-- content[1] Doesn't exist
});
```

Comment: I should write:   const contentId = additionalDetail.content[0].id; AND
const content = (additionalDetail.content) ? additionalDetail.content[0].label : undefined;
RIGHT?

Comment: Yes, or `const content = additionalDetail.content[1] && additionalDetail.content[1].label`, which ill check for the presence of `additionalDetail.content[1]` and if it exists, take the `.label`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the properties of additionalDetails by using any of `Object.keys`, `Object.values`, or `Object.entries`.

```js
const product = {
  id: "id1",
  title: "ProductName 1",
  additionalDetails: {
    o1: {
      id: "pp1",
      label: "Text",
      content: [{
        id: "ppp1",
        label: "Tetetet"
      }]
    },
    o2: {
      id: "pp2",
      label: "Text2",
      content: [{
        id: "ppp2",
        label: "Tetetet2"
      }]
    }
  }
}

for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(product.additionalDetails)) {
  console.log(`Detail ${k} has label ${v.label}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the id index of an array

`o1: {id: "pp1", label: "Text", content: [{id: "ppp1", label: "Tetetet"}]},`

```
const contentId: string = additionalDetail.content.id;
```

You need to select an index of the array to get to the object containg the content id:

```
const contentId: string = additionalDetail.content[0].id;
```

You should also initialize additionalDetails with const.

Comment: I changed it and it does not work. U are right about it but smt else is also a problem. I updated my post.

Comment: You need to use 0 as the index since you just have one item in the array. It starts from 0